# Ionic Capacitor open file in Android not working

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

My app is in Ionic 6 with capacitor.
I should have pdf and jpg files open in the smartphone browser.
From Chrome it works on Android and iOS does not.
How can I do?

```
async openAttachments(attachment: UserAttachmentDTO) {

if (attachment.AttachmentType == AttachmentType.LINK) {
  window.open(attachment.FilePath, '_blank');
  return;
}

//Se è un FILE di tipo DICOM allora richiama l'URL per il DICOM VIEWER
if (attachment.UserAttachmentType == UserAttachmentTypeEnum.DICOM || attachment.FileExtension.toLowerCase().includes("dcm")) {
  this.openDicomAttachment(attachment);
  return;
}

if (!attachment.FileDataBase64 || !attachment.FileContentType) {
  let attachFromServer: AttachmentDTO = await this.attachmentService.getByID(attachment.FK_Attachment);
  attachment.FileDataBase64 = attachFromServer.FileDataBase64;
  attachment.FileContentType = attachFromServer.FileContentType;
}
console.log(attachment);

let extension = attachment.FileExtension.toLowerCase();
if (extension.includes("pdf") || extension.includes("png") || extension.includes("jpg") || extension.includes("txt") || extension.includes("rtf")) {
  let attachmentWindow = window.open("", '_blank');
  attachmentWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:" + attachment.FileContentType + ";base64, " +
    encodeURI(attachment.FileDataBase64) + "'></iframe>");
  attachmentWindow.document.title = attachment.FileName;
}
else {
  let source = `data:${attachment.FileContentType};base64,${attachment.FileDataBase64}`;
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = source;
  link.download = `${attachment.FileName}.${attachment.FileExtension}`
  link.click();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening files in native ionic apps you should use native plugins. Try [file opener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener) plugin. If it didn't work, keep searching for suitable plugin. Each one of them might be deprecated or not working in your case. If you couldn't find a plugin for your case you have to write one yourself with native android and iOS codes. Check out [capacitor plugins](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins).